# Formating JSON from Laravel Eloquent Response

Tags: json, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a response from Eloquent and i need to format it exactly as followed :

```
{
    name: "James",
    data: {
      "2017-01-01 00:00:00": 300,
      "2017-01-02 00:00:00": 600,
    }
  },
```

The current response i am getting is :

```
{
name: "James",
date: "2017-01-01 00:00:00",
amount: "300"
},
{
name: "James",
date: "2017-01-02 00:00:00",
amount: "600"
},
```

I have tied this, but the format is not correct :

```
 $chartData = [];

    foreach($charts as $chart){

        array_push($chartData, [
            'name' => $chart->name,
            'data' => json_encode([$chart->date. ':' .$chart->amount], true)
        ]);

    }
```

Result is :

```
{
name: "James",
data: "{"2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z":"300"}"
},
{
name: "James",
data: "{"2017-01-02T00:00:00.000000Z":"600"}"
},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

$chartData = [];

```
foreach($charts as $chart){

    array_push($chartData, [
        'name' => $chart->name,
        'data' => $chart->date. ':' .$chart->amount
    ]);

}
```

json_encode($chartData);

Comment: that returns - data: "2019-12-03 00:00:00:1000" and i need - data: {"2019-12-03 00:00:00:1000"} also in separate objects

Answer (score 0):

This have to be done on 2 steps:

```
function normalizeChartData($charts){
    $chartData = [];
    //1) grab dates and amounts for each name.
    foreach($charts as $chart)
        foreach($chart->data as $data){
            if(isset($chartData[$chart->name]) && is_array($chartData[$chart->name]))
              $chartData[$chart->name][$data->date] = $data->amount;
            else
              $chartData[$chart->name] = [$data->date => $data->amount];
        }
    //2) format it to look as you want.
    $enhancedChartData = [];
    foreach($chartData as $name => $date_amount){
        $temp = [
            'name' => $name,
            'data' => []
        ];

        foreach($date_amount as $da)
            $temp['data'][] = $da;

        $enhancedChartData[] = $temp;
    }
    return $enhancedChartData;
}
```